# Datediff , coalesce function throwing error in redshift

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift, coalesce

```
select * from 
          (select
          convert (timestamp, '1970-01-01 00:00:00') as Fixed_Date,
          DATEDIFF (Second, 
                   Fixed_Date::timestamp, 
                   COALESCE(detection::timestamp, Fixed_date::timestamp) 
                   )as TTD_seconds,
          row_number() over(partition by a.number order by a.sys_updated_on desc, 
          a.record_processed_datetime desc ) as rn
          from Table a
          )
where rn = 1
```

Detection column has null values, i want my datediff to return 0.
entering 0 is throwing me error as well.
appreciate all the help

error screenshot :

[image]

Comment: It sounds like you have a value that cannot be converted to a `timestamp`.

Comment: @Avni - I don't see any issues with the query. I would check the Select COALESCE(detection::timestamp, Fixed_date::timestamp,'1900-01-01 00:00:00')   to see if the problem persists.

Comment: @VarunTiwari :  select
convert (timestamp, '1970-01-01 00:00:00') as Fixed_Date,
DATEDIFF (Second, Fixed_Date::timestamp, COALESCE (u_time_to_detection::timestamp, fixed_date::timestamp,'1970-01-01 00:00:00') )as TTD_seconds,
from table a

I some how got this working by your suggestion, but when i add my row number syntax it throws me the same error

Comment: select * from 
                 (select
                 convert (timestamp, '1970-01-01 00:00:00') as Fixed_Date,
                 DATEDIFF (Second, Fixed_Date::timestamp, COALESCE 
                 (u_time_to_detection::timestamp, fixed_date::timestamp,'1970-01-01 
                 00:00:00') )as TTD_seconds,
                 row_number() over(partition by a.number order by a.sys_updated_on desc, 
                 a.record_processed_datetime desc ) as rn
                 from Table a
          )
where rn = 1

Comment: @GordonLinoff: I am providing timestamp itself,  i really dont know why its not accepting as a  timestamp. thank you for your input.

Comment: @avni - Glad that you made some progress. Is the error still same ?

Comment: @avni - can you add the query and error screenshot together.

Comment: For some reason neither convert ,cast was working correctly in my case.
This worked in my case, converting it to the format i need.
 
cast ( TO_Timestamp ('1970-01-01 00:00:00','YYYY/MM/DD HH24:MI:SS') as timestamp)

Comment: @VarunT Thanks for your suggestion and input

Comment: You are welcome. Glad that you were able to solve it.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need an alias for your subquery.

```
SELECT * 
FROM (SELECT CONVERT(timestamp, '1970-01-01 00:00:00') as Fixed_Date, 
             DATEDIFF (Second, Fixed_Date::timestamp, COALESCE (u_time_to_detection::timestamp, fixed_date::timestamp,'1970-01-01 00:00:00') )as TTD_seconds, 
             row_number() over(partition by a.number order by a.sys_updated_on desc, a.record_processed_datetime desc ) as rn 
      FROM Table a ) as AA
WHERE rn = 1
```